# Let $p$ be a prime number. $ord_p(ab)=ord_p(a)+ord_p(b)$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that $ord_p$ has the following property.
$ord_p(ab)=ord_p(a)+ord_p(b)$. (Thus $ord_p$ resembles the logarithm function, since it converts multiplication into addition!)

In my book, they describe the order as the exponent of the term in the prime factorization. But how do I use this to proof this statement?

Comment: A way I know this notation is written is actually $v_p(a)$. $ord_p(a)$ is actually for the smallest number $t$ so that $a^t\equiv1\mod p$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \   \overbrace{c\,p^{\large\, j}}^{\large a}\:  \overbrace{d\, p^{\large k}}^{\large b}\, =\, \overbrace{cd\ p^{\large\, j+k}}^{\large ab}.\ $ If $\ p\nmid c,d\ $ then $\ p\nmid cd\ $ (by $\,p\,$ prime)

thus $\ v_p(a)+v_p(b)\, =\, j+k\,=\, v_p(ab)$

**Remark** $\ $ This can also be deduced directly from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations). Above is essentially the same but for a single prime $\,p,\,$ i.e. the existence and uniqueness of factorizations of the form $\  n\,p^j\,$ where $\  p\nmid n.$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\text{ord}_p(a)=m$ and $\text{ord}_p(b)=n$.

Then $a=p^mr$ where $p\not|r$, and $b=p^nq$ where $p\not|q$. So $ab=p^{n+m}$ and $p\not|qr$,
so, $\text{ord}_p(ab)=m+n=\text{ord}_p(a)+\text{ord}_p(b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, there exists unique prime factorizations for $a$ and $b$. If we let $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots$ be all prime numbers, then we may write their factorizations as $$a=p_{1}^{r_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}}\cdots$$

and $$b=p_{1}^{s_{1}}p_{2}^{s_{2}}\cdots$$

where all but finitely many of the $r_{i}$ and $s_{i}$ are zero. Then, we have $$ab=\left(p_{1}^{r_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}}\cdots\right)\left(p_{1}^{s_{1}}p_{2}^{s_{2}}\cdots\right) = p_{1}^{r_{1}+s_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}+s_{2}}\cdots.$$

Finally, if we let $p=p_{i}$ for some $i$, we have that $\text{ord}_{p}\left(a\right)=r_{i}$, $\text{ord}_{p}\left(b\right)=s_{i}$, and $\text{ord}_{p}\left(ab\right)=r_{i}+s_{i}=\text{ord}_{p}\left(a\right)+\text{ord}_{p}\left(b\right)$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=p^{\alpha} p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ and $b=p^{\beta} p_1^{\beta_1}\dots p_n^{\beta_n}$.(some exponents can be zero so the primes coincide)

Then $ab=p^{\alpha+\beta} p_1^{\alpha_1+\beta_1}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n+\beta_n}$.

From here $ord_p(a)+ord_p(b)=\alpha+\beta=ord_p(ab)$